# ImageButton doesn't work after once clicked

Tags: android

I made a button to delete a ListView item. It works fine on first click, but if I try to click again, it doesn't work anymore.

Here is the onClickListener code:

```
    OnClickListener clickBtnExcluir = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (taskManager == null) {
            taskManager = new AsyncTaskManager(context);
            final Entity entity = (Entity) v.getTag();
                            Service service = new Service();
                            taskManager.executeTask(service, new String[] { cod1, cod2 }, new OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener<Return>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onTaskCompleteSuccess(Return result) {
                                    if (result == Return.YES) {
                                        refreshList();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onTaskFailed(Exception cause) {

                                }

                            });
                        }
        }
    };
```

And here is the `refreshList` method

```
public void refreshList() {
    taskManager = new AsyncTaskManager(context);
    ListService listService = new ListService();

    taskManager.executeTask(listService , new String[] { cod1, "1", "0" },
            new OnAsyncTaskCompleteListener<List<Entity>>() {

                @Override
                public void onTaskFailed(Exception cause) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTaskCompleteSuccess(List<Entity> result) {
                    listView.refreshDrawableState();
                    mainList = result;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            });
}
```

Someone have any ideia?

Sorry by grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after the first click, taskManager is not null anymore, so you don't go through the executing code

Comment: Perfectly well noted @Rahl_Pryde

Answer (score 1):

According to your code above, the onClick will work on once {and thats what is happening}

I guess you want to check the Status of your AsyncTask before adding another async for executing:

For that please replace your if with this line

```
if(taskManager.getStatus()==Status.FINISHED){ //check required status

    }
```

dont forget to check this before any other condition:

```
if(taskManager!=null){

    }
```